# Calculate repeat users for an online app

Tags: sql

Developed an internal web application for folks to request reports. Plan to calculate the repeat users by month and week to measure the impact of the product.

Repeat users by month : Users who have requested for reports in m1 and have come back on m2. If one has requested a report in m1 but has again requested in m3 those will NOT be counted as monthly repeat users. Same thing applies to week, quarter and year.

The table contains many columns but the key one's are : user_id, action_date

Here's the query im using:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT user_id
     ,date_trunc('month', action_date) AS month
     ,count(*) AS reports
     ,lag(date_trunc('month', action_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY  user_id
                                       ORDER BY date_trunc('month', action_date)) 
      = date_trunc('month', action_date) - interval '1 month'
        OR NULL AS repeat_transaction
           FROM   a
   WHERE  action_date >= '2016-01-01'::date
--AND    action_date <= '2016-12-01'::date -- time range of interest.
GROUP  BY 1, 2
)
SELECT month
    ,count(*) AS num_users
    ,count(repeat_transaction) AS repeat_users
 FROM   t
 GROUP  BY 1
 ORDER  BY 1;
```

Here's the output from the query:

[image]

I did a quick check manually via excel to verify the values. Here's the actual figures[image]

Hence clearly, the query numbers for month of november is off and i'm not sure why. Any help here would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please define "users" and "repeat users".  Sample data and desired results are helpful for this purpose.

Comment: this is not mysql so I have removed the tag

Comment: @GordonLinoff - have explained how are the repeat users defined. Users are those who have requested reports. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this postgres? You may be better off using cross join lateral with a correlated subquery to determine if a user did use the service in the prior month. I cant see how deducting a month is a true test of repeat use. Sample data would assist.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data there's an element of guesswork in attempting to answer this, and there's isn't any way to reliably reproduce your issue without the exact same data. In a simple test (see below) al I can suggest is that you remove the group by that you have in the cte, it isn't required. I have also dispensed with the cte as there is no technical advantage it using one here.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/305af/2)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable    
    ("user_id" int, "action_date" timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ("user_id", "action_date")
VALUES
    (1, '2016-09-05 00:00:00'),
    (3, '2016-09-05 00:00:00'),

    (1, '2016-10-05 00:00:00'), -- repeat
    (2, '2016-10-05 00:00:00'),

    (1, '2016-11-04 00:00:00'), -- repeat
    (2, '2016-11-04 00:00:00'), -- repeat
    (3, '2016-11-04 00:00:00'), 
    (4, '2016-11-04 00:00:00'),

    (1, '2016-12-04 00:00:00'), -- repeat
    (2, '2016-12-04 00:00:00')  -- repeat
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT
          month
        , count(*) AS num_users
        , count(repeat_transaction) AS repeat_users
    FROM   (
              SELECT user_id
                 , date_trunc('month', action_date) AS month
                 , lag(date_trunc('month', action_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY  user_id
                                                   ORDER BY date_trunc('month', action_date)) 
                    = date_trunc('month', action_date) - interval '1 month'
                    OR NULL AS repeat_transaction
               FROM   MyTable
               WHERE  action_date >= '2016-01-01'::date
          ) t
    GROUP  BY 1
    ORDER  BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/305af/2/0)**:

```
|                       month | num_users | repeat_users |
|-----------------------------|-----------|--------------|
| September, 01 2016 00:00:00 |         2 |            0 |
|   October, 01 2016 00:00:00 |         2 |            1 |
|  November, 01 2016 00:00:00 |         4 |            2 |
|  December, 01 2016 00:00:00 |         2 |            2 |
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I still get the same output as before. 0 for the month of novemeber

Comment: Without data that reproduces  your problem this question will remain unanswered